# Stack Trace Error for RefTableId field assignment

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I created a new table and added a new Integer field (called RefTableId) with an EDT of the standard RefTableId type. Writing NewTable.RefTableId = tableNum(SomeTable); compiles but during run time I get this stack trace error: "Error executing code: Wrong argument types in variable assignment."

I've even tried NewTable.RefTableId = 0; This still fails.  And yes, I've triple checked that it is indeed an integer field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really stupid, the line before the assignments was reading .data() out of a FormListItem object that had invalid data in it.  Instead of showing an error for that line, it skips over it and fails the assignment lines below.  It makes no sense to me since I wasn't using any information from that FormListItem object to populate any field data with, yet still caused that to fail for some reason.  I'm going to mark this one in the "Bang Head Here" category.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in a class, be sure to do a compile of all `super` classes as well as a compile forward (child classes). Remember to do an incremental CIL.

If it still fails do a full compile (`axbuild`).

Comment: The code exists within a form.  Also, I have "Execute business operations in CIL" turned off in my DEV.  I will avoid the full compile as of now because it is a shared DEV environment and don't want to suspend their productivity.

Comment: Did you assign the table buffer before assigning the field?
If so, test whether the buffer is of the correct type (in the debugger).

Comment: Yes it is the correct type, I'm not using Common or anything similar.  I've also double checked with the debugger.

Comment: If it is a new table in a shared development system, an failed data synchronisation could also be the cause, so maybe try a synchronisation of the complete data dictionary.

Comment: I assume you have recompiled the form. In that case something nasty happened, like memory corruption. Try restart both the AOS and client, and see if it goes away.

Comment: Yeah, this is really weird, I've added a button to the InventParameters form.  Inside the clicked method I'm trying to assign values to fields on a table buffer, brand new table, not using data sources, and trying to insert the record.  I've commented out line by line, all assignments fail.  My RefTableId, RefRecId, even a string field.  I've even tried duplicating the new table object (exporting to XPO, Notepad edit the name and clear out all GUIDs, and re-importing) and referencing that, still no luck.  I don't know what to do here.